# How does Eclipse do code completion specific to third-party frameworks?

Tags: eclipse, code-completion

How does the Eclipse editor work to enable code completion?  For example, within the XML editor for Hibernate property files, if I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd> within a tag, a list of possible value relevant to hibernate will show up.

[image: Eclipse suggests fields defined in a Java class within a Hibernate hbm.xml file.]

I understand that the XML editor is pre-configured to understand xml tag, but how about tag specific to a particular framework?  How does Eclipse know about that?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the eclipse XML editor gets the content assist information from any referenced DTDs, or XMLSchema information it associates with the XML file.  Try this experiment:  Remove the DOCTYPE entry at the beginning of the file and see if content assist still works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in writing your own content assistants, you may want to start by reading the following:

http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/editors_contentassist.htm

In a nutshell, like most things in Eclipse, this is a platform hook. When you press the button, it queries all the registered assistants (I'm simplifying here), and they provide suggestions based on the current element or even the current content.

When writing a source editor or viewer for a particular language or document type, it is common to provide at least some rudimentary content assistants.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23072/uri)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308744/eclipse-editor-ex-xml-editor-code-assistance-how-it-works/2308752#2308752), you can define your own editor for your own language with **[XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/)** as long as you have a simple [EBNF grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) language for your DSL (domain specific language).

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse/xtext/master/plugins/org.eclipse.xtend.doc.xdoc/xdoc/images/getting-started-editor.png]

You will have:

- syntax coloring,
- model navigation (F3, etc.),
- code completion,
- outline view, and
- code templates.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the DOCTYPE entry at the beginning of the file and im now able to see the commands while typing ctrl+space...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution you can work. Actually I was facing a same problem with `struts.xml` file. I was not able to produce tags by `cntrl+space`

what i did was...

go to `Preferences...Java...Editor...Content Assist...Advanced`

check all the check-boxes ON and press OK.

sometimes the problem persists due to some false alarming in eclipse. If it happens, just delete your xml file and create a new one in same location.

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using the struts.xml file.
I got fix when I tried below...
Go to  **“Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced“**. Make sure **“Java Non Types Proposals”** are ticked on both the places as shown in the image below then click Apply and OK button:-

[image]