# is there one way to turn on code assist in animation xml

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Eclipse give me a good experience in code assistence.But when it comes to animation xml files and i enter alt+/,it pop up nothing.So it make me very easy to type a wrong attribute name because of my poor english.can you give me a hand?
thanks.

Comment: ps:i have change the short-cut key ctrl+space to alt+/ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your animation xml file is location in `anim` folder not `animation` folder

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "animation xml file" (the [CEGUI ones](http://www.cegui.org.uk/api_reference/xml_animation.html)? [Android ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136258/how-to-load-animationdrawable-from-xml-file)?), but, as explained in "[eclipse editor, ex: xml editor, code assistance. how it works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308744/eclipse-editor-ex-xml-editor-code-assistance-how-it-works/2324158#2324158)", any xml file with auto-completion needs a DTD or Schema informtion.
Sometime, the `DOCTYPE` at the beginning of the xml file can prevent the auto-completion to work.

Comment: for example, the <alpha> tag have no code assistence.but when i edit the layout xml

Comment: @user674199: do you have any link to a reference to what you are calling "animation xml file"? That would help for asserting if any code assistance is available. Knowing that there is an `<alpha>` tag isn't enough ;)